# How to find the ODBC driver name for a connection string?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, postgresql, odbc, amazon-redshift

Whenever I use ODBC drivers with a full connection string, and not just a DSN entry, I often get an error similar to this

```
Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

I have the correct syntax of the connection string (or so the Internet says), but I suspect I don't know the correct name for the current version of the ODBC driver I am using

How do I find the correct name, for either 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the ODBC Data Source Administrator app. Make sure you use the 32 bit or the 64 bit version depending on your applications build target. Then select the "File DSN" tab

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]

Click the "Add" button, and select the driver you have installed

[image: "Add" button]

Then click the "Advanced" button

[image: "Advanced" button]

You can then copy and paste the correct driver name, and cancel out of the ODBC Data Source Administrator app

e.g.

```
DRIVER={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)}
```

Add the rest of the parameters required, and you will have a working ODBC connection string for the currently installed version of the driver

e.g.

```
Driver={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)};Server=ruru.nz;Port=5432;Database=TheInternet;Uid=tfd;Pwd=p455w0rd;
```

Enjoy :-)

Comment: I followed most of these steps, buw how do you get the Server, Port, Database and Uid?

Comment: Hi @bernando_vialli, as the article title says this is "How to find the ODBC driver name" not how to get the db info. If you search on the site for the correct topic surely you will find what are you looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-OdbcDsn -Name "[dsn-name]" -DsnType "[system|user|file]" -Platform "64-bit"`

You can use powershell to get it as well. And possibly build the full connection string.

```
$dsn = Get-OdbcDsn -Name "dsn-plus" -DsnType "user" -Platform "64-bit"
$dsn
$dsn.DriverName
#$dsn.Attribute

$connecton_string = 'driver="' + $dsn.DriverName + '";'
foreach ($key in $dsn.Attribute.Keys) {
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($dsn.Attribute[$key])) {
        $connecton_string = $connecton_string + $key + ";";
    } else {
        $connecton_string = $connecton_string + $key + "=" + $dsn.Attribute[$key] + ";";
    }
}

$connecton_string
```