# SQL Server connection with jQuery and node js

Tags: jquery, sql-server, node.js

I am using node js to connect to a SQL Server that has only Windows authentication. The database is stored on a centralised machine.

The database returns some json data which I place at some address (http://10.2.9.208:8081/me). This is the address of my PC i.e, (https://localhost/me) and I retrieve it using a jQuery call.

This jQuery call is made from a html page to retrieve jsonp formatted data to avoid cross origin problems.

This is my jQuery call in a page index12.html

```
$.get("http://10.2.9.208:8081/me?callback=?", function (data) {

        dataset_module_errors = data;
    });
```

The connection strings are in a page app.js

My connection string which I used to connect with database was

```
var config = {
server: '10.2.12.153',                          
database: 'DFMProAnalyticsCopy',       // my table is within this server
port: 1433                             // default port number
};
```

This throws an error 'LOGIN ERROR' as it considered user & password as '' -> null strings.

So I eventually used this for windows authentication

```
var config = 
"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
Server=10.2.12.153,1433;
Database=DFMProAnalyticsCopy;
Trusted_Connection={Yes}";
```

Now this throws two errors ->

1. ConnectionError: Unknown driver SQL Server Native Client 11.0!
2. GET http://10.2.9.208:8081/me?callback=? 500 (Internal Server Error)

I have referred to [How to find the ODBC driver name for a connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254191/how-to-find-the-odbc-driver-name-for-a-connection-string) to find the driver name and have verified it twice.

All of this has been working perfectly fine when I accessed my local database installed on my PC through the JQuery call. I had user SQL Authentication on my PC.Windows authentication gives the error

```
login failed for user ''
```

when accessed through  node js.

I have done some mistake in accessing the central DB.

Please guide me through it.

EDIT 1: Since this is Windows authentication, I do not have a username or password

Comment: You want use ODBC name or connected directly? For connect throw ODBC your connection-string contain only ODBC-alias. If you connected directly look at your version of SQL-client and write Driver= correctly.

Comment: Hi, I have written the driver name from the SQL client only. I did not understand how I can find the driver name otherwise, if not using ODBC

Comment: Is this connection-sting using by *dot* *net* *odbc*? if yes try Driver={SQL Server}  For example: Driver={SQL Server};Server=10.0.0.1;Database=myDB;Uid=db_login;Pwd=db_passw   (may be login and password must be using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form Connection-string for OdbcConnection is

Driver=**{SQL Server}**;Server=10.0.0.1;Database=db_alias;Uid=db_login;Pwd=db_passw

Do not change driver parametr.
And thanks Suchitra Iyer, for local server connection-string is

"Server={10.2.9.208};Database=trialdb;Uid=;Pwd="

Comment: Hi, I do not have the Uid and Pwd. If I simply omit them, I get the login failed for user "" error

Comment: Without using ODBC can I connect to my server through Windows authentication?

Comment: I do not now. Create user and restrict access. It's be quickest sollution.

Comment: Hi, we have to use UserID and Pwd only for Sql authentication right? But I am using WIndows authentication.

Comment: Hi, This worked for me finally //var config = "Server={10.2.9.208};Database=trialdb;Uid=;Pwd="; on my local server